# fetch array and move array to object in php

Tags: php, json

```
while ($array = $photo_items->fetch_array()) {
    echo $array['img_src'];
echo "<br />";
}
```

I don't want to use fetch object because I want this array to be within another object.

the current result is 1.jpg2.jpg

what I want is

```
{
    otherproperty: 'something',
    img : ['1.jpg'],['2.jpg'];
}
```

in json

Comment: Please elaborate, it's not clear what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply, try this way

```
    $json_array = array('otherproperty' => "something", "img" => array())
    while ($array = $photo_items->fetch_array()) {

        array_push($json_array['img'], $array['img_src'])

    }
    echo json_encode($json_array);
```

Comment: @user3346088, ok you just push $json_array into another statement